# Android List View Clickable with redirection

Tags: android, listview, search, android-edittext, items

I'm on a project to android app, I created a list view with items, even normal.
The user can search for items in an edit text, I just love that now the user can click on an item and be redirected to another activity.
I can do redirection, no problem for that. How can I make a switch that research in the table if such checkbox item1 do this etc ... So how could I do this?
Sorry for my English, I'm French, good day

Here is the code :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

String[] items;
ArrayList<String> listItems;
ArrayAdapter<String>adapter;
ListView listView;
EditText editText;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtsearch);
    initList();
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            if (s.toString().equals("")) {
                initList();
            } else {
                searchItem(s.toString());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

    });

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView,
                                View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    listView.setBackgroundColor(17170459);
                    finish();
                    break;

                case 1:
                    listView.setBackgroundColor(17170453);
                        finish();
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}

public void searchItem(String textToSearch){

    for (String item:items){
        if (!item.contains(textToSearch)){
            listItems.remove(item);
        }
    }

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


public void initList(){

    items= new String[]{"item2","item3","test"};
    listItems = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item,R.id.txtitem,listItems);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);




}
```

}

Comment: How can I make a switch that research in the table if such checkbox item1 do this etc ... this is not clear.. you said redirection is ok that means activity change on item click is ok.... so what do you want actually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first sorry for posting an answer instead of a comment but I have not enough reputations  to post a comment.

You want to know in your "itemActivity" on which item you clicked on the previous activity, am I right ?

Then launch a new activity thanks to an Intent, and you can precise the position of the item you clicked on with an EXTRA :

```
Intent i=new Intent(context,itemActivity.class);
i.putExtra("quelItem", position);
startActivity(i);
```

You can find the position in your ItemActivity class like this :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int quelItem= intent.getIntExtra("quelItem");
```